# Can we create a stackexchange.com/faq (currently 404) or remove the link from this page?

Tags: bug, status-completed

On this page: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new

> Rooms are expected to be on the same topics as The Stack Exchange Network, as described in the [The Stack Exchange Network faq](https://stackexchange.com/faq).

Also there's a double "the The" in there that one of the "the" needs to be removed.

The existing page being referred to: https://stackexchange.com/faq is currently 404.

Comment: They're testing us to see if we actually read the FAQs before doing whatever we want. We failed

Comment: Ah, isn't Paris beautiful? Nice catch.

Comment: I noticed it once long ago, and figured it was an issue of the SE site being too new, and that it would catch up.

Comment: @PopularDemand I missed the Paris reference ... Pandas, on the other hand, are awesome.

Comment: http://www.opendb.net/media/content/614.gif <-- common item in lists of optical illusions

Comment: @PopularDemand nice. I've always seen it as "a bird in the the hand is worth two in the bush", same concept tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done and done; sorry about that.

Comment: wait, what? I goto http://stackexchange.com/faq and it's not there ... what am I doing wrong? - Oh, I see what you did there, you just removed that sentence. Gotcha :D